# /etc/sudoers - Insults - How to add a list of insults?

Tags: linux, sudo

I intend to play with the linux insults and add a few. However, i only could figure how to add a single insult but not a list or the location of the file that contains the insults.

Comment: You can't add any insults to sudo without editing the source.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To edit the list of insults, you will need to edit the source and recompile.

The insults are stored in `plugins/sudoers/ins_*.h` (4 files). If you add a new file, you will need to add its definition to `plugins/sudoers/insults.h`. That's it.

Answer (score 4):

For me on the Debian side, I ended up writing a sudoers.d directive to achieve the result, because adding a list of custom insults requires *recompilation* of `sudo`.

- https://gist.github.com/tonejito/235feb4f1d299fd82ad513289b4704ee

In my custom config I use two directives

1. One for *boring* systems where `sudo` is compiled without `insults`, here I use `badpass_message` to hardcode a *single* custom insult which appears in every bad password message
2. A directive for the *fun* systems where `insults` is supported on `sudo`

You must enable **either** `insults` or `badpass_message`, enabling both falls back to `insults` (at least on Debian).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as I have not used this funny(?) feature before but I have find this [sudoers insults help](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1134078) and [Insult me, sudo!!!](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/insult-me-sudo-366518/) and other references that suggest that this "feature" have to be enabled compiling `sudo` from sources.

I guest that (since it's fun but useless) that many *nix do not include it at all and if they do that list is hardcoded into the `sudo` executable.

To obtain this you have to edit `/etc/sudoers` (using `visudo` ) and add this directive:

```
Defaults insults
```

On OSX 10.8.4 (sudo version 1.7.4p6) you can check the active `Defaults` using :

```
$ sudo -l | grep insult
    XAUTHORIZATION XAUTHORITY", env_keep+="EDITOR VISUAL", env_keep+="HOME MAIL", insults
```

Then you can try it using:

```
$ sudo -K
$ sudo ls
```

and if you write a wrong password you'll see the "insult"

But I have tested all this on OSX 10.8.4 and it do not work, you get the standard `Sorry, try again.` message.

I have searched the output of

```
$ sudo strings `which sudo`
```

but ther are no such strings.

**NOTE:**
I'll test it on other *nix (as soon as I can) and report.

Comment: Could you add some of the specifics here to your answer? Would make your answer much stronger.

Comment: @Aurigae wasn't asking how to enable the insults, but how to add a custom one...